# Duplication in HTML datalist using JQuery with more than one clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I design a datalist on web page. And I want to fill this datalist  using JQuery. Controller execute a query and get a list of facilities. Then pass this list to client side. This datalist can show all the facilities. When user click this textbox, the facilities will be listed in drop down list. But when user click more than once, there will be duplicates in datalist. That means, if you click twice, the result will be shown twice in datalist.

Here is code in MVC view

datalist:

```
    <input type="text" list="facility" autocomplete="on" name="Facility" id="facilities" />
    <datalist id="facility"></datalist>
```

JQuery Code:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#facilities').click(function () {
                //alert("Clicked");
                var postData = $('#clientTxt').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("FacilityCheck", "PCA")',
                    data: { clientTxt: postData },
                    success: function (result) {
                        //successful
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.facilities.length; i++) {
                            //alert(JSON.stringify(result.facilities[i]));
                            var option = "<option value ='" + result.facilities[i] + "'>" + result.facilities[i] + "</option>";
                            //I want to add an if judgement to avoid duplicates here
                            //Like contains() method in JAVA.
                                $('#facility').append(option);

                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('Oh no :(');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

The duplicates image after clicking many times:
[image]
So please give me some advice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using the jQuery `append()` method and not replacing the HTML. Right now, you're just adding (appending) to it every time you iterate through your loop of `result.facilities[i]` instead of replacing the content.

Your best bet would be to add all of that source to a string and replace the `$('#facility')`'s `innerHTML` with the new content. You can use `$('#facility').html(yourContentString);` to do so.

Hope this helps!

For example...

```
success: function (result) {
   var options = "";
   //successful
   for (var i = 0; i < result.facilities.length; i++) {
       var option = "<option value ='" + result.facilities[i] + "'>" + result.facilities[i] + "</option>";
       options = options + option;
   } //end of loop
   $('#facility').html(options); // replace the innerHTML of #facility with your new options string
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify your success like this :

```
$('#facility').html('');
$('#facility').append(option);
```

Remove the items before appending them.

You can also use empty :

```
$('#facility').empty();
```